# Employee community license type

Tags: employee-community

can we use employee community license type to extend access to custom objects? Is there a limit on number of custom objects using this license type. Salesforce's licenses have been changing and i cant seem to locate what is possible and not possible using this license type. can these users login using regular salesforce login URL or can access only through community sites?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5)

Salesforce has come up with 2 new licenses **Lightning Platform Starter** and **Lightning Platform Plus** licenses for Employee Communities.

> We have three Communities licenses for external users: Customer
>   Community, Customer Community Plus, and Partner Community. We also
>   have Lightning Platform Starter and Lightning Platform Plus licenses
>   for Employee Communities.

Regarding custom objects Lightning Platform Starter users can have access for 10 custom objects and  Lightning Platform Plus  users can have access for 110 custom objects.

There is no systemic way to prevent access if you provide access to more custom objects but it could result in contract violation with salesforce if they catch in audit.

Talk to SF representative on your project to get pricing information.

Comment: Non related but related question, if you have a project that only require a single license, and no CRM Objects, can you have a Lightning Platform Starter? or you still need to get a full license in the org?

Answer (score 0):

@RedDevil, thank you!

Found the source for

> Lightning Platform Starter and Lightning Platform Plus licenses for Employee Communities.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.community_templates.meta/community_templates/users_license_types_communities.htm

Curiously, it is not in SF docs.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5